# Hide image until hover

Tags: html, css

I've been at this a while now and can't seem to get the behavior I'm looking for.

Bare bones here is what I have:

HTML

```
<ul>
<div class="container">
    <li class="preview-image" style="background-image:url(https://www.w3schools.com/Html/pic_trulli.jpg); height: 100px;">
      <div class="txt-container">
        <a>Title</a>
        <p>Desc</p>
      </div>
      <a class="btn">Button</a>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

The background image url has to be done as part of the HTML because I am looping through a list of items, each item has an image property. The above image url is an example image. In actual code it is `{{ item.image }}`, which can only be accessed via HTML.

CSS

```
.preview-image {
  opacity: 1;
} 
.container:hover .preview-image {
  opacity: 1;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.container:hover .txt-container {
  opacity: 0;
}
.txt-container {
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}
.btn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
```

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coq9sdxu/) is close to what I want. I want the bg image to take up the entire `li`. I only want the image visible on hover of the `li` (or containing element). While hovering, the `Title` and `Desc` should be hidden so they do not interfere with the viewing of the image. The `Button` should stay visible at all times. The result I'm looking for is exactly the behavior of this fiddle, except the image is only seen on hover.

I can't just set the opacity or visibility on the `li` itself since it has multiple classes on it. I only want the visibility to affect the background image. I also have tried making a `div` and placing it inside the `li`, but I can't get it to fill the `li` space anymore. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but try this:

```
 <ul class="nopadding">
<div class="container">
    <li class="preview-image" style="background-image:url(https://www.w3schools.com/Html/pic_trulli.jpg); height: 100px;">
      <div class="txt-container">
        <a>Title</a>
        <p>Desc</p>
      </div>
      <a class="btn">Button</a>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>


.preview-image {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100vw;
}
.nopadding {
  padding: 0!important;
} 
.container:hover .preview-image {
  opacity: 1;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.container:hover .txt-container {
  opacity: 0;
}
.txt-container {
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}
.btn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
```

EDIT: Try this then:

```css
.preview-image {
  background-image: none;
  width: 100vw;
}
.nopadding {
  padding: 0!important;
} 
.container:hover .preview-image {
  opacity: 1;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image:url(https://www.w3schools.com/Html/pic_trulli.jpg); height: 100px;
}
.container:hover .txt-container {
  opacity: 0;
}
.txt-container {
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
.btn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
```

```html
 <ul class="nopadding">
<div class="container">
    <li class="preview-image">
      <div class="txt-container">
        <a>Title</a>
        <p>Desc</p>
      </div>
      <a class="btn">Button</a>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

EDIT: Without background-image in CSS:

```css
.preview-image {
  background-size: 0 0;
  width: 100vw;
}
.nopadding {
  padding: 0!important;
} 
.container:hover .preview-image {
  opacity: 1;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100px;
}
.container:hover .txt-container {
  opacity: 0;
}
.txt-container {
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
.btn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
```

```html
 <ul class="nopadding">
<div class="container">
    <li class="preview-image" style="background-image:url(https://www.w3schools.com/Html/pic_trulli.jpg);">
      <div class="txt-container">
        <a>Title</a>
        <p>Desc</p>
      </div>
      <a class="btn">Button</a>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: That is close, but I still want the `Title`, `Desc`, and `Button` to be visible before the hover.

Comment: Added second version of code in my answer, see if that's what you needed?

Comment: Great! No problem :)

Comment: Actually, sorry, I didn't notice. The CSS you have uses a background image property. I can't use that property in CSS because I don't have access to it on the CSS side. I only have it on the HTML side which is why I have the `style`.

Comment: Updated with a third version

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class to the `li` tags, then you can use CSS to only display the background image on hover. Something like this:

HTML:

```
<li class="img-hover">
  ...
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.img-hover:hover {
   background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/Html/pic_trulli.jpg");
 }
```

Comment: I can't add the image on the CSS side because, as I am looping through a list, each list item's image property is only available via HTML side.

Comment: You could use IDs instead of classes. that way you can have multiple in your CSS file, defining a different picture for each one.